# Modify the header of the merge method so that it can receive as parameters (and return) stacks that are either array-based or reference-based?

Tags: java, stack

Basically my code works fine but I would like to update it to be more flexible so any ideas on how I can modify the header of the merge method so that it can receive as parameters (and return) stacks that are either array-based or reference-based? I'm gonna post some of the code, if more is necessary then I will update it. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * merge: Given two stacks containing Integer objects in increasing order from the bottom up, 
 * create a third stack such that the Integer objects are in decreasing order from the bottom up.
 * If an item appears n times in the two given stacks, it will appear n times in the new stack.
 *
 * @param s1  the first stack
 * @param s2  the second stack
 * @return    the new stack, with the items from the two given stacks merged.
 */
 public static StackReferenceBased merge(StackArrayBased s1, StackReferenceBased s2)
 {
 StackReferenceBased newStack = new StackReferenceBased();
 Integer i1 = new Integer(-1);
 Integer i2 = new Integer(-1);

 if (!s1.isEmpty())
    i1 = (Integer)s1.pop();

 if (!s2.isEmpty())
    i2 = (Integer)s2.pop();

 while (!s1.isEmpty() && !s2.isEmpty()) {

   System.out.println("Comparing " + i1 + " and " + i2);

   if (i1.compareTo(i2) < 0) {
        newStack.push(i2);

        //Get next item from second stack
        i2 = (Integer)s2.pop();
   }
   else {
         newStack.push(i1);    

         //Get next item from first stack
         i1 = (Integer)s1.pop();
   }
 }

 // At this point, s1 and/or s2 are empty. 

 if (s1.isEmpty()) {
    newStack.push(i2);
    while (!s2.isEmpty()) {
       newStack.push(s2.pop());    
    }
 }

 if (s2.isEmpty()) {
    newStack.push(i1);
    while (!s1.isEmpty()) {
       newStack.push(s1.pop());    
    }
 }

 return newStack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the signature to accept and return the common interface, `StackInterface`:

```
public static StackInterface merge(StackInterface s1, StackInterface s2)
```